# Outlook 2016 - whitelist certain addresses from domain

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

Let's say I work for XYZ Ltd and our email addresses are name@xyz.ie .

I have three colleagues jane@xyz.ie. mary@xyz.ie, ahmed@xyz.ie .

However I get spam with spoofed sender addresses say (apparently) from dave21@xyz.ie and mike99@xyz.ie and other obviously randomly generated names.

So can I create an Outlook rule to only allow the three or four valid names from the domain and spam folder the rest?

Comment: Surely you should be investigating and fixing why this is happening - there are various ways your email admin can help significantly reduce (or even stop) your domain being spoofed...

Comment: Well I'll put a ticket in, maybe they can do some sort of whitelist ...